# _TOTAL_ token not displaying the number of records in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, datatables

I am trying to use  [datatables](http://datatables.net) and i want to display the total number of records in the top left where i have the option to change the number of rows

[image]

my code for datatable is as below:

```
tableT= $('#empDataTable').DataTable({


         "language": {
             "lengthMenu": "Show _MENU_  of _TOTAL_ entries"
            // "zeroRecords": "Nothing found - sorry",
           //  "info": "Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_",
           //  "infoEmpty": "No records available",
           //  "infoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total records)"
         },

//          fixedHeader: true,
        scrollY: 300,
        scrollX : false,
        deferRender: true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        scroller: false,
        mark: true,
        columnDefs: [

                    { type: 'date-dd-mmm-yyyy', targets: 5 }

                    ],
    dom: 'lfrtBp',
    buttons: [
    { extend: 'excel', text: 'Export to Excel',className:'btn btn-primary btn-xs',
        exportOptions: {
                columns: [ 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 ]
            }

    }

    ]

     }
     );
```

But for some reason i am not able to display/evaluate the _TOTAL_. [Documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.info)

I want to display the _MENU_ and _TOTAL_ together in lengthMenu so that the user understands at a glance that in total how many entries are there and how many records are shown

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$('#empDataTable').dataTable( {
  "language": {
    "info": "Show _TOTAL_ entries",
    "lengthMenu": "Display _MENU_ records"
  }
} );
```

Comment: I want to display the \_MENU\_ and \_TOTAL\_ together in lengthMenu so that the user understands at a glance that in total how many entries are there and how many records are shown

Answer (score 0):

Try using DataTable's `dom` option.

```js
$('#empDataTable').DataTable({
  // "dom": "<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'f>><'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>><'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
  "dom": "<'row'<'col-sm-6'li><'col-sm-6 hidden-xs'f>><'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>><'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
});
```

`l -> li` = `length + Table info(total count)`

> https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom

This is css to merge into one line.

```css
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length,
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length + .dataTables_info {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```